# Почему не работает Matcher.find()

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка String str и в ней надо найти символы строки 1

```
 1=0;1;123.456;4;5;6;5;
 2=1;2;451.467;6;7;8;6;
 3=2;3;765.654;8;3;2;4;
 4=1;2;451.467;6;7;8;6;
```

есть

```
Pattern pattern;
Matcher m;
String s="1=(.+?)2=";
pattern = Pattern.compile(s);
    m = pattern.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {Log.d("MyLog","Найдено");};
else {Log.d("MyLog","Не найдено");};
```

Результат: "Не найдено". Почему?

Comment: А обязательно вообще проверять наличие 2=? Если нужа оставшаяся часть строки, можно использовать `1=(.*)` / `(?m)^1=(.*)`

Comment: Попробовал. Не пошло. m.find() ничего не находит с этим параметром.

Comment: А вот [тут всё находится](https://ideone.com/DtUcGT). Ну да ладно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы ваш код работал, так как вы ожидаете добавьте флаг `Pattern.DOTALL` при создании объекта `Pattern`:

```
 pattern = Pattern.compile(s, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Без этого режима, регулярное выражение вида `.` не подходит для символа новой строки.

[Ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) на документацию по регулярным выражениям в **java**

Comment: Возникла еще задача. Заменить найденную строку на другую. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Получаете объект Matcher и вызываете на нем метод replaceAll

Comment: Да, но почему то "съедаются" два символа до и после. Т.е."1=" и "2=" пропадают. Почему это может быть?

Comment: Потому что они являются частью регулярного выражения, соответственно тоже подлежат замене. Чтобы такого не происходило, необходимо либо явно написать в строке на которую будет происходить замена недостающий текст. Либо, переписать регулярное выражение, заключив текст который не следует удалять в скобки, тогда в тексте на который будет происходить замена писать $<номер группы скобки в регулярном выражении><текст замены>. Т.е. для вашего случая это выглядеть будет так: regex - "(1=)(.+?)(2=)" replacement = "$1<текст замены>$3"

Comment: Понятно! Спасибо!

Comment: @kaaa пожалуйста)